# Write all days of period for each single account from a single data table

Tags: t-sql

I have a data table with daily transactions on several bank accounts. I would like to calculate the sum of the transactions on each bank account for each day within a certain time period. For days where there was no transaction during that period, I want to see a NULL value.

I am using two tables: one with the transaction data and one calendar table.

I was able to get the desired result for a single account with the code shown below (ZWID is the ID of the bank account)

```
WITH sum_transactions as
(
  SELECT csd.ZWID, csd.ValueDate, sum_total = sum(csd.amount) 
  FROM myDataBase.CashData as csd
  WHERE csd.ValueDate > '20190131' and csd.ValueDate <= '20190208'
  AND csd.ZWID IN (1592)
  GROUP BY csd.ZWID, csd.ValueDate
)

SELECT st.zwid, cal.Calendar_Date, st.sum_total 
FROM treasury.dbo.calendar as cal
LEFT JOIN sum_transactions as st on st.ValueDate = cal.Calendar_Date
WHERE cal.Calendar_Date > '20190131' and cal.Calendar_Date<= '20190208'
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

I get the following (desired) output:

```
zwid    Calendar_Date   sum_total
1592    2019-02-01   606174,09
NULL    2019-02-02  NULL
NULL    2019-02-03  NULL
1592    2019-02-04  -600000
NULL    2019-02-05  NULL
NULL    2019-02-06  NULL
NULL    2019-02-07  NULL
NULL    2019-02-08  NULL
```

i.e. there were two days with transaction(s) on that specific bank account in the period.

Now, when I add a second account (ID 1593) (to the IN statement), I would hope to get a second set of 8 new rows (for 01 Feb to 08 Feb) with either a sum or a NULL value (a total of 16 rows for both accounts).

However, I now get a result table that shows no rows with NULL values for the first account anymore (apart from the two days where both accounts show no transactions).

```
zwid    Calendar_date   sum_total
NULL    2019-02-02  NULL
NULL    2019-02-03  NULL
1592    2019-02-04  -600000
1592    2019-02-01  606174,09
1593    2019-02-01  -847958,75
1593    2019-02-04  303105,26
1593    2019-02-05  -285312,64
1593    2019-02-06  502762,95
1593    2019-02-07  405372,02
1593    2019-02-08  326213,87
```

Obviously, I do not succeed in having the query write all Dates for each account separatly.

How do I need to change my query for it to run through one bank account, write all days of the period (value or NULL) and only then move on to the next account?

Update: I am looking at a large number of bank accounts. The number of accounts will change over time

Comment: I think my updated answer will help - let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: @MISNole: that is fantastaic! Exactly what I had been looking for! Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you need, try it out and let me know.  But basically I had to use a `CROSS APPLY` to the full list of IDs/Dates you were looking for and then I used the rest of your code to get your desired results:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Test;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #FullCalendar;

CREATE TABLE #Test
    (
        ZWID INT ,
        ValueDate DATE ,
        Amount MONEY
    );

INSERT INTO #Test ( ZWID ,
                    ValueDate ,
                    Amount )
VALUES ( 1, '20190101', 100.00 ) ,
       ( 1, '20190101', 75.00 ) ,
       ( 1, '20190108', 75.00 ) ,
       ( 1, '20190110', 50.00 ) ,
       ( 2, '20190101', 25.00 ) ,
       ( 2, '20190102', 35.00 ) ,
       ( 2, '20190103', 50.00 ) ,
       ( 2, '20190103', 125.00 ) ,
       ( 3, '20190102', 150.00 ) ,
       ( 3, '20190109', 100.00 ) ,
       ( 3, '20190110', 75.00 ) ,
       ( 3, '20190110', 75.00 );

SELECT dd.Date, t.ZWID
INTO #FullCalendar
FROM dbo.DateDimension AS dd
CROSS APPLY #Test AS t
WHERE dd.Date >= '20190101' AND dd.Date < '20190111'
GROUP BY dd.Date ,
         t.ZWID
--SELECT * FROM #FullCalendar ORDER BY ZWID, Date

;WITH sum_trans AS (

SELECT
t.ZWID, t.ValueDate, sum_total = SUM(t.Amount)
FROM #Test AS t
GROUP BY t.ZWID ,
         t.ValueDate )

SELECT fc.Date, fc.ZWID, st.sum_total
FROM #FullCalendar AS fc
LEFT OUTER JOIN sum_trans AS st ON st.ZWID = fc.ZWID AND fc.Date = st.ValueDate
ORDER BY fc.ZWID,fc.Date;
```

Leaving my old answer here as well.

I was able to get your desired result by using 2 CTEs and a UNION ALL:

```
WITH sum_transactions as
(
  SELECT csd.ZWID, csd.ValueDate, sum_total = sum(csd.amount) 
  FROM myDataBase.CashData as csd
  WHERE csd.ValueDate > '20190131' and csd.ValueDate <= '20190208'
  AND csd.ZWID IN (1592)
  GROUP BY csd.ZWID, csd.ValueDate
) ,
WITH sum_transactions2 as
(
  SELECT csd.ZWID, csd.ValueDate, sum_total = sum(csd.amount) 
  FROM myDataBase.CashData as csd
  WHERE csd.ValueDate > '20190131' and csd.ValueDate <= '20190208'
  AND csd.ZWID IN (1593)
  GROUP BY csd.ZWID, csd.ValueDate
)

SELECT st.zwid, cal.Calendar_Date, st.sum_total 
FROM treasury.dbo.calendar as cal
LEFT JOIN sum_transactions as st on st.ValueDate = cal.Calendar_Date
WHERE cal.Calendar_Date > '20190131' and cal.Calendar_Date<= '20190208'
ORDER BY 1, 2

UNION ALL

SELECT st.zwid, cal.Calendar_Date, st.sum_total 
FROM treasury.dbo.calendar as cal
LEFT JOIN sum_transactions2 as st on st.ValueDate = cal.Calendar_Date
WHERE cal.Calendar_Date > '20190131' and cal.Calendar_Date<= '20190208'
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Comment: Thank you MISNole! I forgot to emphasise that I am looking at a large number of bank accounts. And the number of accounts will change rather regularly. Hence your approach is perfect for a limited and stable number of accounts but it does not yet quite solve my problem, I'm afraid.